# What is the meaning and application of ren'youkei?

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

My knowledge about ren'youkei is limited to "tabe is the ren'youkei of taberu". I would like to know what the meaning of ren'youkei is, what linguistic idea lies behind this term and for what it is actually used in everyday usage.

Answer (score 10):

The 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") is one of the various 活用形｛かつようけい} ("inflected forms") for 用言{ようげん} ("inflectable words") in Japanese.

The way I like to explain this is somewhat non-standard, but I think more coherent than how it is usually explained. I will connect this explanation back to the standard way at the end.

---

I think there are two things worth discussing:

1. The `-I` Form
2. The Continuative Form

## The `-I` Form

The `-I` form is `stem-I`: the stem of an inflectable word plus the -I morpheme.

**`-I` definition:**

- Vowel-stem verb: `∅`
- Consonant-stem verb: `i`
- i-adjective: `∅`

**Examples:**

- Consonant-stem verb 思う: `omow-I -> omo(w)-i -> 思い`
- Consonant-stem verb 行く: `ik-I -> ik-i -> 行き`
- i-adjective 熱い: `atsu-I -> atsu-∅ -> 熱`
- Vowel-stem verb 食べる: `tabe-I -> tabe-∅ -> 食べ`

The `-I` form feels a lot like a noun.

**Uses:**

- The continuative form

  - See later for examples.
- -sou and -sugi-

  - **熱**そう
  - **行き**そう
  - **熱**すぎる
  - **食べ**すぎる
- Compounding

  - **早**起き
- Stand-alone nouns (I can only think of verbs here)

  - **思い**
  - **考え**
  - **感じ**

## The Continuative Form

The continuative form (a.k.a., 連用形) is `stem-I-CONT`: the stem of an inflectable word, plus the `-I` morpheme, plus the `-CONT` morpheme.

**`-CONT` definition:**

- Verbs: `∅`
- i-adjectives: `ku`

**Examples:**

- Consonant-stem verb 思う: `omow-I-CONT -> omo(w)-i-∅ -> 思い`
- Consonant-stem verb 行く: `ik-I-CONT -> ik-i-∅ -> 行き`
- i-adjective 熱い: `atsu-I-CONT -> atsu-∅-ku -> 熱く`
- Vowel-stem verb 食べる: `tabe-I-CONT -> tabe-∅-∅ -> 食べ`

**Uses:**

- Adjuncts:

  - **間違いなく**怒っている。
  - **優しく**抱きしめる。
  - 君のことを**思い**、彼を許した。
- Conjunction (this form is known as the 中止形):

  - 外へ**行き**、マスコミに話す。
  - 空は**青く**、地面は茶色。
- -te:

  - **熱く**て
  - **食べ**て
  - **思っ**て (omo(w)-i-te after euphonic changes, namely 促音便)
- Various auxiliaries, e.g.:

  - -mas-: **行き**ます
  - -tutu-: **直り**つつ

---

While this is hardly complete, maybe it helps give an idea of what the 連用形 is. The way this stuff is usually taught, I think the -i form is often conflated with the 連用形, because the surface form is the same for verbs, but I think it makes more sense to split it out like this.

Comment: So, you're pretty much categorizing adjective stems under "i-form"? Interesting. Also, there are a couple of standalone nouns (doubling as adverbs) that come from 連用形 of i-adj, like 多く, 近く, 遠く, and 早く

Comment: What does "surface form" mean? And do verbs that have a su ending have a shi added to their stem form via continuative form?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey “Surface form” is in contrast to “underlying form”. The underlying form is stuff like ik-PLAIN, where the surface form is iku. When you presupose morphemes that have null surface forms (like I do in this post) it’s very easy to have a surface form which has an ambiguous parsing into underlying representations.

Comment: Also, your second question isn’t precise enough to give a short answer without reexplaining some of the concepts in this post. Try again? (If you’d like.)

Answer (score 4):

Japanese has two main categories for standalone terms: 用言{ようげん} and 体言{たいげん}.

- **用言** inflect: this category includes verbs, *-i* adjectives, and *-na* adjectives.
- **体言** don't inflect, and this category includes nouns, pronouns, and numbers.

These two terms form the basis of the terms for two different conjugations: the 連用形{れんようけい} and the 連体形{れんたいけい}.

- **連用形** literally breaks down as 連 "goes with / attaches to" + 用 short for 用言 + 形 "form" -- this is the form of the word (conjugation) that attaches to other words that also conjugates.
  So when combining verbs into a compound verb, you use the 連用形.  Or when using an adjective (a part of speech that inflects) to modify another adjective or a verb (which also inflects), you use the 連用形.
  Since this form (and the meaning of the underlying term) *continues* into the following inflected term, this is often glossed in English as the **"continuative form"**.
- **連体形** literally breaks down as 連 "goes with / attaches to" + 体 short for 体言 + 形 "form" -- this is the form of the word (conjugation) that attaches to other words that *don't* conjugate.
  So when modifying a noun or other non-inflected term with a verb or adjective, you use the 連体形.
  Since this form is used to describe an *attribute* of the following uninflected term, this is often glossed in English as the **"attributive form"**.

Notably, the 連用形 for verbs is sometimes used as a noun: for instance, 替{か}わり is the 連用形 for 替{か}わる, and it is also a noun meaning "replacement, alternative".

Also, the 連体形 and the 終止形{しゅうしけい} (literally "terminal form", the form to use when an inflected word is at the end of a sentence) used to be distinct, but these have become the same thing in modern Japanese (except for *-na* adjectives -- these use な for the 連体形 and だ for the 終止形).

For more about Japanese conjugation forms, see the Wikipedia article on [Japanese grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar), particularly the bit on [Conjugable words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Conjugable_words).

For more about older Japanese where these two forms were still distinct, see the Wikipedia articles on [Classical Japanese language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Japanese_language) and [Early Middle Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Middle_Japanese).

Comment: I like your answer in paritucar for mentioning 体言 and 用言 but I think there is a little typo: 蓮 (as in 蓮根) instead of 連 sometimes.

Comment: あら、変換ミス！すぐ修正します。