# What is this ~れ verb form used in the middle of the sentence? Is it ~られて/~れて without the て?

Tags: て-form, renyōkei, subordinate-clauses, passive-form, noun-clauses

I saw this sentence in a light novel.

> 浮遊感に穏やかに**包まれ**、玉響の安息。

What is this verb form 「包まれ」? It looks like it's supposed to be 「包まれて」but with the て dropped. I've seen this form every now and then, but I haven't been able to find an explanation.

Could someone explain what it means and when this is used? Is this a conjugation used for dramatic written Japanese or songs or writing in general? Is its meaning the same as the ~れて form or does it have a completely different meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33256/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29725/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a te-form of 包まれる = 包む + れる.

To me, it is the same as 包まれて, but using 包まれ is more literary. Using te-form alone is called 連用中止法 (see [this](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/12/06/jlptn3-grammar-renyoochuushi/) for example). Generally it gives a succinct impression. As such, it goes well with the noun ending (安息) here.

Comment: So it's just the verb stem grammar that acts like "and" for verbs like て-form but with a more literary usage for written Japanese like in books, articles, or songs, right? So it wouldn't be used much in spoken/everyday Japanese unless you were trying to sound dramatic or poetic? Also, would it be correct to say that 包まれ is the verb stem of 包まれる (the passive form of 包む), especially since conjugating a verb to its passive form is essentially like creating a new る-verb?

Comment: @littlecatte Regarding the first point, basically yes. It is used in news or reporting as well. Re the second, it may be the case in the sense that 包まれ is the part shared by all forms. But grammatically 包まれる is a compound and れ is the te-form of れる. Also FYI, not all verbs admit dropping て.  E.g. for 食べれる (a 'ら抜き' potential form), 食べれて cannot be 食べれ.