# る dropped from passive form?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, passive-voice, renyōkei

I'm currently translating some song lyrics for my own understanding (境界線 by Amazarashi) - I had some confusion on the following line:

> 境界線の向こう側で　忘れ去られ
> 終わる定め　そう知りながら
> 屈服することを　許さぬあの声は
> かつての戦友か　己の心か

Per [online translation](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/ky%C5%8Dkaisen-border.html), it means "Beyond the border, I can forget my ending fate. I understand.
The voice that doesn't allow you to give in, is it from your former comrades or is it from your own heart?"

It seems to me that 忘れ去る here is in the passive form, 忘れ去られる, but the る is dropped. Does anyone understand why this is / under what conditions you can drop the る? It's also possible I'm misunderstanding the grammar, as I'm pretty new to studying Japanese, so please let me know if this is the incorrect interpretation. Thanks!

Comment: Should be a dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94826/45489

Comment: Note that these four lines form one big sentence, and that online translation does not reflect this fact. Everything before あの声 is a long relative clause. A literal translation of this verse is "Is that voice—which does not allow submission, knowing that we are destined to be forgotten and come to an end on the other side of the boundary line—a former comrade or my own heart?" 忘れ去られ is in the continuative form because it's actually in the middle of a clause (be forgotten **and**...).

Comment: yes! thanks for your help :)